Zscaler - Microsoft "Pick an account" dialog
I have 2 email accounts in my Outlook and when I have to login to the second account it shows me this dialog:

I usually click "No, sign in to this app only", but this time I clicked "OK". After that Zscaler started logging me out every 24h and I had to choose my account from the Microsoft "Pick an account" dialog:

I'm pretty sure it's because Outlook somehow added that account to Windows, how do I remove it?

In the end, I managed to remove it by going to Control Panel -> Accounts -> Access work or school, and then I clicked "Disconnect this account" for the account which Outlook had added:

